# Program crashing after using an open() on an ajax call in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the following code, I get an alert for 1, but the program does not go past the open(). I am not sure why this is crashing, it seems pretty basic.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   alert('1');
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/playlist.json');
   alert('2');
xhr.send(null);
```

EDIT:
By crash I mean that the second alert never pops up. I can't get the rest of the code to work, so it seems to be a problem with the open line. I am running this in jsfiddle, if that makes a difference.

EDIT 2:
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1vg009hm/3/

Comment: Crashes how? Any error messages?

Comment: The alert shows perfectly fine.

Comment: That code should be fine. Is there any messages in your developer console?

Comment: Seems to work just fine? Of course you're missing the `readyState` event handlers and everything else to actually get the data, and when you have those, you'll realize there's something called the same-origin policy

Comment: And jsFiddle doesn't get links with no SSL anymore, only https

Comment: Thanks Adeneo. I tried with an https link instead, and the second alert popped up. I had no idea that jsFiddle didn't work with SSL. If you want to leave an answer, I'll mark it as correct.